# Keras - custom loss function - Computing squared distance of softmax output from truth label

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am training a classification problem that ends in a softmax layer. I want to compute the loss as the average of the product of the prediction probability and square distances of each example's softmax output from the truth label.

In pseudocode: average(probability*distance_from_label**2)

Right now I am using the following code, which runs, but converges to outputting '0' for every instance. There is something wrong in its implementation:

```
bs = batch_size
l = labels
X = K.constant([[0,1,...,l-1] for y in range(bs)], shape=((bs,l))
X = tf.add(-y_true, X)
X = tf.abs(X)
X = tf.multiply(y_pred, X)
X = tf.multiply(X, X)
return K.mean(X)
```

Is there a way to implement this square difference loss function and keep a softmax layer? And still to measure the actual Euclidian distance between the predicted and true labels, not just the element-wise difference in one-hot vectors?

For clarity, I have provided these examples:

**Example 1:**

label1 = [0, 0, 1, 0], prediction1 = [1, 0, 0, 0]

loss1 = 4 = (4 + 0 + 0 + 0) = (1*2^2 + 0*1^2 + 0*0^2 + 0*1^2)

**Example 2:**

label2 = [0, 1, 0, 0],prediction2 = [0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3]

loss2 = 1.8 = (0.3 + 0 + 0.3 + 1.2) = (0.3*1^2 + 0.1*0^2 + 0.3*1^2 + 0.3*2^2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Tensorflow (or Theano) as well as Keras Backends when designing a custom loss function. Note the tf.multiply and other functions from Tensorflow.

The following code implements this custom loss function in Keras (tested and working):

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    bs = 1 # batch size
    l = 4 # label number
    c = K.constant([[x for x in range(l)] for y in range(bs)], shape=((bs, l)))

    truths = tf.multiply(y_true, c)
    truths = K.sum(truths, axis=1)
    truths = K.concatenate(list(truths for i in range(l)))
    truths = K.reshape(truths, ((bs,l)))

    distances = tf.add(truths, -c)
    sqdist = tf.multiply(distances, distances)

    out = tf.multiply(y_pred, sqdist)
    out = K.sum(out, axis=1)

    return K.mean(out)

y_true = K.constant([0,0,1,0])
y_pred = K.constant([1,0,0,0])
print(custom_loss(y_true, y_pred)) # tf.Tensor(4.0, shape=(), dtype=float32)
```

Comment: could you give more insight into how you implemented this? how can I create graphs with batch size & label number as a variable?

Comment: @SebastiaanvanBaars - maybe you've already figured out with your edit, but more insight is I did a lot of trial and error. Consulted [the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Loss) a lot, and [articles like this one](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/04/advanced-keras-constructing-complex-custom-losses-metrics.html). 

Additionally, you might also be interested in [this coursera course](https://www.coursera.org/specializations/tensorflow-advanced-techniques) about advanced TF techniques including custom loss functions

Answer (score 0):

Hereby another implementation which achieves the same objective with slightly different weights. Note: the one-hot labels need to be dtype=float32. All credits go to my supervisor.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow.keras as keras
 
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(5, activation="relu"))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax"))
opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=1e-3, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, decay=0.0, amsgrad=False)
 
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):

    a = tf.reshape(tf.range(tf.cast(tf.shape(y_pred)[1],dtype=tf.float32)),(1,-1))
    c = tf.tile(a,(tf.shape(y_pred)[0],1))
    x = tf.math.multiply(y_true,c)
    x = tf.reshape(tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=1),(-1,1))
    x = tf.tile(x,(1,tf.shape(y_pred)[1]))
    x = tf.math.pow(tf.math.subtract(x,c),2)
    x = tf.math.multiply(x,y_pred)
    x = tf.reduce_sum(x, axis=1)
    return tf.reduce_mean(x)
     

 
yTrue= np.array([[0,0,1,0],[0,0,1,0],[0, 1, 0, 0]]).astype(np.float32)
y_true = tf.constant(yTrue)
y_pred = tf.constant([[1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3]])
custom_loss(y_true,y_pred)
 
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss=custom_loss)
model.fit(np.random.random((3,10)),yTrue, epochs=100)
```